# Number of size $k$ sets from $n$ sets of possibly different size

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-theory

I have $n$ finite sets of integers (possibly of different size) and I want to determine the number of size $k$ sets I can make from them such that each "$k$-set" contains at most one integer from each set. For example, consider the following sets:
$$
\{1,2,3\}\\
\{4,5\}\\
\{6,7,8\}\\
\{9\}
$$
If $k=3$, then a few valid $k$-sets would be $\{1,4,6\}$, $\{2,4,6\}$, $\{3,8,9\}$, and $\{5,7,9\}$.

The best solution I've come up with for computing the number of of $k$-sets is basically what they teach you in grade school to compute the number of possible phone numbers: multiple the sizes of the sets together in groups of $k$ and add them all up. For the above example, this would be: $3*2*3+3*2*1+3*3*1+2*3*1=39$. Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: I assume your sets are disjoint. If the sizes of the sets are $n_i$ then the answer is the coefficient of $t^k$ in $(1 + n_1 t)(1 + n_2 t) \dots (1 + n_i t)$. Expanding this out gives what are called the elementary symmetric polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in the $n_i$ and this doesn't simplify any further.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan perhaps worth saying this is a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) and that $(1+3t)(1+2t)(1+3t)(1+t) = 1+9t+29t^2+39t^3+18t^4$ confirming the $39$ sets of size three as well as telling you the numbers of sets of other sizes

Comment: The way you have formulated the question, the number of possible $k$-sets is indeterminate. For example, for $n=4$ and $k=2$, if the sets are  {1}, {2}, {3}, and {4}, then there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ $k$-sets, but if instead they are {1}, {2}, {3}, and {4, 5}, then there are ${3 \choose 2}+2{3 \choose 1}=9$ of them.

Comment: @Paul: what do you mean? That just says that the answer isn't solely a function of $n$ and $k$ but I don't think the OP implied it was.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, OP refers twice to those four sets as an example.

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan and Henry. This is as good of an answer as I could've hoped for. I like that you can determine other "$k$-set" sizes at the same time too!

Comment: Also, feel free to convert your comment into an answer that I can accept if that's important to you.